# EWS Api 2.0 not returning ID of copied Appointment

Tags: c#, vb.net, exchangewebservices

I'm having a problem with "Copy" method of "Item":
As explained in documentation ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634844(v=exchg.80).aspx)) that method should return the copied item (and the relative fresh UniqueId), but I can only get a null return object.

```
Dim obj = existingItem.Copy(folderId) 'obj is null
```

I've also tried:

```
Dim test = service.CopyItems(myListOfItemIds, folderId)
```

This is returning something, but still not copied item UniqueId in it...

Does it exists a workaround for this problem? Am I missing something?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you copying the Item between two folders in the same mailbox or between two folders in different mailbox as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600291(v=exchg.150).aspx

> If you're moving or copying an email message between two folders in the same mailbox, the new item is returned in the response, which gives you access to the new item ID. However, if you're moving or copying an email message between two mailboxes or between a mailbox and a public folder, the new item is not returned in the response

Comment: Well thank you, I've missed this... I'm copying between two calendars of different users. So the only way is to search again for the inserted item? Nothing more fast/linear?

Comment: Yes if its two different Mailboxes you need to will need to enumerate the items from the Target.